# How to get Windows phone Store AppID?

Tags: facebook, api, windows-phone

I am planning on creating a Windows Phone application which will interact with Facebook. In order to use the Facebook-Development API, I need a Windows Store AppId to register with Facebook. How do I create a Windows Store AppId? Which URL should I use to get it?

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Phone, you need to access your Windows Phone Dev Center account using your developer credentials.

Next, if you haven't already, create a new app using the 'Submit App' button. You will need to do this even if the app isn't finished yet. Fill out as much of the information as you can right now.

Once you are done creating the information, return to your Dashboard and click on the newly created app under 'In-Progress Submissions.' On the new page that results, click the 'Details' tab and scroll down to about halfway to find 'App ID' in the right column. The GUID directly beneath it is your AppId. I hope this helps.